# Redis messages in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, redis

I am having problems with httpd full memory usage and we are trying to find the cause. 
We have installed Redis and Full Page Cache, we have run this command

> redis-cli monitor

and we see thousands of the messages of the screenshot, where are?
Thanks

[image]